# SQL LIKE query in Tarantool

Tags: sql, sql-like, tarantool

What is a proper way to make a query in Tarantool DB with SQL LIKE keyword?
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM space where smth LIKE '%some_value%';
```

Can I search for values using a part of index or I need to write my own LUA script for such functionality?

Comment: I'd think since Tarantool is NoSQL you won't be able to use SQL syntax for writing queries.

Comment: @Alex, starting tarantool version 2.0 tarantool supports sql

Comment: Thank you @o2gy, the question is dated 2016, and the first alpha's of version 2 were release few years later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you shoud write Lua Script, that'll iterate over space and use lua function `gsub` on `'smth'` field of tuple.
There's no way, for now, to search for part of string.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your query if you use tarantool version 2.x.

```
SELECT * FROM "your_space" WHERE "smth" LIKE '%some_value%';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use stored procedure for optimal prefix-based search.
For example, this snippet works with cyrillic texts too:

```
box.schema.create_space('address')
box.space.address:create_index('prefix', { type = 'tree', parts = { { 1, 'str', collation = 'unicode_ci' } }, unique = true })

select_by_prefix = function(prefix)
    local result = {}
    for _, addr in box.space.address.index.prefix:pairs(prefix, { iterator = 'GT' }) do
        if utf.casecmp(utf.sub(addr[1], 1, utf.len(prefix)), prefix) == 0 then
            table.insert(result, addr)
        else
            break
        end
    end
    return result
end
```